# Not able to loop array properly condition getting failed -reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Trying to loop array list using for loop , but condition getting failed if it satisfies.

if there is 2 array list , say 1 is having data and other is not having data

it is looping through only first array, but not with other array list.

i am just checking if values are empty ,undefined and 0.

I am popping alert message if  array list doesn't have value, but at first list if data is available and its coming out of loop but it is not checking the other value is satisfied or not.

can i get some suggestion on this. please

here is my code below

```
areWidgetsEmpty = (currentWidgetList) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < currentWidgetList.length; i++) {
    const widget = currentWidgetList[i];
    switch (widget.widgetType) {
    case WidgetTypes.venn: {
        const CurrentWidgetRigthValue = widget.rightTargetValue;
        const CurrentWidgetLeftValue = widget.leftTargetValue;
        const CurrentWidgetRightText = widget.rightTarget;
        const CurrentWidgetLeftText = widget.leftTarget;

        return !CurrentWidgetRigthValue || !CurrentWidgetLeftValue || !CurrentWidgetRightText || !CurrentWidgetLeftText;
      };
    default:
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

currentWidgetList

```
0
:
{widgetId: "ee23235b-4034-4443-98fc-47b783610311", widgetName: "widget 0", widgetType: "venn", leftTarget: "PSHGMALE", rightTarget: "PSHGMALE", …}
1
:
{widgetId: "625927bf-bacb-447d-aeb5-517940293c12", widgetName: "Widget", widgetType: "venn", leftTarget: "", rightTarget: "", …}
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your problem is? What is the expected output? Please provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce your bug.

Comment: @HåkenLid i have changed , hope it is specific and understandable

Comment: You have a `return` statement in the for-loop in `areWidgetsEmpty`. When you hit a return statement, you will exit the method after the first widget. Is that what you want? It's not obvious to me what the purpose of this function is.

Comment: ok...may i know what should i do without return...can you help

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to do. I can't run the code, since it's not a **complete** example. [mcve]. There's not enough information here to suggest a solution. What is the input value `currentWidgetList`? What is `WidgetTypes.venn`? Please provide input data and expected output.

Comment: now only i need to loop 2 arrayList and return ....if empty value is satisfied i will display pop up

Comment: @HåkenLid I have updated my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try this. It's not clear what exactly you mean by "empty", but you can define a `nonEmpty` function and use `Array.every()` to check if all items in an array satisfy the condition defined in your function.

```js
const nonEmpty = ({
  widgetType,
  rightTarget,
  leftTarget
}) => widgetType == 'venn' ? rightTarget && leftTarget : true

const areWidgetsEmpty = items => !items.every(nonEmpty)

const widgets = [{
  widgetType: "venn",
  leftTarget: "PSHGMALE",
  rightTarget: "PSHGMALE"
}, {
  widgetType: "other",
  leftTarget: "",
  rightTarget: ""
}]

console.log(areWidgetsEmpty(widgets))
```

Comment: let me try, Thanks